# Get only updated columns by using OUTPUT Clause sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following procedure to track column changes in the table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [UpdateAddress]
@id bigint=0,
@fullname varchar(200)='',
@address varchar(200)='',
@city varchar(200)='',
@state varchar(200)=''
AS
declare @desc varchar(500);
BEGIN
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(  
   fullname varchar(200) NULL,  
   address varchar(200) NULL , 
  city varchar(200) NULL ,
 state varchar(200) NULL );


        BEGIN
            UPDATE [Address]
            SET 
                fullname=@fullname,
                address=@address,
                city=@city,
                state=@state

             OUTPUT deleted.fullname,  
      deleted.address,  
      deleted.city,  
      deleted.state
INTO @MyTableVar
             WHERE [Id]=@id
```

here i will get all columns which are updated and not updated. So we need to compare both like `deleted.fullname and inserted.fullname` . So, if I have 20 columns in a table, and only 2 columns i updated. without comparing , is there any way to get only updated columns using output clause?

Example: I have 20 columns. in that only fullname and address i updated. so i should get Fullname,Address changed. without any comparison. Is there any sql built-in function like updated_column()?

Comment: The simple answer to your basic question is No, there is no intrinsic way to only return the updated data. Comparing inserted and deleted is the intended way to do determine what changed.

Comment: if i have 20 columns, all conditions i have to check then. ok thank you for your reply...

Answer (score 2):

You can use scalar expressions in the `output`.  So, you could represent "no change" as, say, `NULL`:

```
OUTPUT (case when inserted.fullname <> deleted.fullname then deleted.fullname end),  
       (case when inserted.address <> deleted.address then deleted.address end),
       (case when inserted.city <> deleted.city then deleted.city end),  
       (case when inserted.state <> deleted.state then deleted.state end)
```

This is unambiguous if the previous column values are never `NULL`.

You could also use the same idea to list together the columns that are changed:

```
OUTPUT deleted.fullname,  
       deleted.address,  
       deleted.city,  
       deleted.state,
       ((case when inserted.fullname <> deleted.fullname then 'fullname;' else '' end) + 
        (case when inserted.address <> deleted.address then 'address;' else '' end) + 
        (case when inserted.city <> deleted.city then 'city;' else '' end) +   
        (case when inserted.state <> deleted.state then 'state;' else '' end)
       )
```

The expressions would be a bit more complicated to include `NULL` checks.

Comment: I have 20 Columns. So procedure will be heavy...by doing comparison.I already getting both deleted and inserted as i mentioned. So Without this comparison , Can i get only updated columns ?

Comment: Regarding the first example. you could do `case when inserted.fullname <> deleted.fullname then deleted.fullname else 'N/C' end` or other to sigify no change